# Oracle 12c JSON TABLE parsing error handling

Tags: sql, json, oracle, error-handling, oracle12c

Is it possible to handle error while parsing invalid JSON with `JSON_TABLE`?
Like for example below query works

```
SELECT *
FROM 
JSON_TABLE(
    '[{"productCode":"AD","serials":[{"id":"234242343","isPrimary":true}]},{"productCode":"BC","serials":[{"id":"23345345","isPrimary":true}]}]'
    , '$[*]'
    columns(
        productCode varchar2 PATH '$.productCode' NULL ON ERROR,
        serials varchar2 format JSON PATH '$.serials' NULL ON ERROR
    )
);
```

The output for above is as below:

```
|PRODUCTCODE | SERIALS                              |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|AD          |[{"id":"234242343","isPrimary":true}] |
|BC          |[{"id":"23345345","isPrimary":true}]  |
```

Here in the above example, the input JSON is valid, however, in my case, there is no guarantee as its being fetched from another log table.

**I want the query to ignore if it encounters invalid JSON.**

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is transferring your data into new table with check constraint in order to check whether the data in the source table conforms to `JSON` format as being an Oracle 12c+ user.

If the format is false, then the row won't be inserted into that new table such as

```
CREATE TABLE tab_new (
  id      INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  jsdata  VARCHAR2(500),
  CONSTRAINT json_chk CHECK (jsdata IS JSON)
);

BEGIN
  FOR C IN ( SELECT jsdata FROM tab_old )
  LOOP
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO tab_new(jsdata) VALUES(c.jsdata) ;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN IF SQLCODE = -2290 THEN 
                       INSERT INTO tab_error(jsdata) VALUES(c.jsdata) ;
                      END IF;
  END;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cd2c15332c8df890f645da31d97f744c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is json` condition to filter out invalid JSON:

```
create table t (
  what varchar2(20),
  c1   varchar2(500)
);

insert into t 
  values ( 'valid JSON', '[{"productCode":"AD","serials":[{"id":"234242343","isPrimary":true}]},{"productCode":"BC","serials":[{"id":"23345345","isPrimary":true}]}]' );
insert into t 
  values ( 'invalid JSON', '"productCode":"AD","serials":[{"id":"234242343","isPrimary":true}]},{"productCode":"BC","serials":[{"id":"23345345","isPrimary":true}]}]' );
commit;

select what from t
where  c1 is json;

WHAT         
valid JSON
```

But this is unnecessary: `json_table` already ignores invalid documents!

```
SELECT what, j.*
FROM   t, JSON_TABLE(
    c1, '$[*]'
    columns(
      productCode varchar2 PATH '$.productCode' NULL ON ERROR,
      serials varchar2 format JSON PATH '$.serials' NULL ON ERROR
    )
) j;

WHAT          PRODUCTCODE    SERIALS                                 
valid JSON    AD             [{"id":"234242343","isPrimary":true}]    
valid JSON    BC             [{"id":"23345345","isPrimary":true}]
```

You can force an error on invalid JSON with the `on error` clause:

```
SELECT what, j.*
FROM   t, JSON_TABLE(
    c1, '$[*]'
    error on error
    columns (
      productCode varchar2 PATH '$.productCode' NULL ON ERROR,
      serials varchar2 format JSON PATH '$.serials' NULL ON ERROR
    )
) j;

ORA-40441: JSON syntax error
```